# Why does browsers parse <script> tags differently?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, svg

I am developing a new site and while writing some client side HTML/Javascript code, I came across this scenario.

If there is HTML encoded characters within the `<script>` tag, for example, `<script> alert("&gt;");</script>`, an alert has to popup with `&gt;` and it does because I believe the HTML parser runs first before the javascript parser for `<script>` and `<style>` tags. This works as expected.

Now, when writing some code, I did this - `<svg><script>alert("&gt;");</script></svg>`. This time I am getting a popup with `>` instead of `&gt;`. Although I can understand it is because of the `<svg>` tag, I am not sure what the underlying reason is and what other tags besides `<svg>` changes the default behavior.

If someone can point to an official documentation, that would be so helpful.

Here is a simple JSFiddle I created for this scenario - https://jsfiddle.net/emz8Lfxt/.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Your SVG tag is unclosed, and now browsers are confused as to whether the SVG is around the script tag (which would make no sense by the way) or before it. Close your SVG tag and see if things work differently. You can verify that your HTML is valid using this site. https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Comment: Closing the svg tag bears no impact on what the user is demonstrating. Try it yourself. I'll note I upvoted his question to counter your downvote; regardless of some inconsequential copy-paste, the question is an interesting one.

Comment: @Crayons - Thank you! Closing the svg tag after </script> tag has no impact.

Comment: closing the tag before or after the script tag does make a difference.

Comment: Closing the svg tag makes no difference in Chrome. Can you advise, what browser are you using @epascarello? Perhaps this is a browser-specific rendering quirk.

Comment: `<svg></svg><script></script>` and `<svg><script></script></svg>` does make a difference.

Comment: Of course it would, because the script is no longer encompassed by the svg. Personally, I assume the user is explicitly referring to placing the script inside the svg tags, as is evident with his provided fiddle; otherwise he'd just be demonstrating the same thing twice, which I feel would defeat the purpose.

Comment: It is the svg processing the content which processes the entity. Every browser does it.

Comment: @Crayons I did not downvote

Comment: @epascarello this demonstrates what I was trying to say. The SVG element’s end is unclear and I don’t know what each browser does with that. I imagine cross-browser you’d find inconsistencies, because it’s not valid.

Comment: My point still stands though: validate your html and you’ll avoid confusing quirks like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Truthfully, I feel you would be hard-pressed to find official documentation on why this occurs.

My best guess in this scenario, is that since the SVG element is a container for SVG graphics, and that the SVG container is XML based, and can contain other HTML elements within it; example:

```html
<svg>
    <rect style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);" />
</svg>
```

The browser tries to parse the inner html, in an effort to draw the object. However, once it realizes its not truly an SVG element, is just stops and proceeds to execute the javascript you've got there instead. As a consequence, `&gt;` gets parsed before the javascript ends up being executed.

I feel like we'd need someone with in-depth knowledge on the particulars of how an SVG element is processed.

I'll note, for reference, this sample:

```html
<script>alert("&gt;")</script>
<svg><script>alert("&gt;")</script></svg>
<span><script>alert("&gt;")</script></span>
```

Will output, in order:

```sh
&gt;
>
&gt;
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. I am leaning towards your answer after reading through the W3 docs. :)

Answer (score 1):

Browsers parse `<script>` specially, they don't replace HTML entities in them. This allows you to write things like:

```
if (a < b)
```

rather than having to write:

```
if (a &lt; b)
```

In early browsers, you had to write something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<![CDATA[
  …
]]>
</script>
```

The `CDATA` section didn't perform entity substution, so you could write code "normally" in there.

But later HTML specifications made this the default for `<script>` bodies, so it's no longer necessary.

But when the `<script>` is inside `<svg>`, apparently the SVG parser takes precedence. So `&gt;` is being translated to `>`.

Comment: Are there any other tags besides `<svg>` where the HTML entities are resolved within `<script>` tags?

Comment: I don't know offhand. As mentioned in the other answer, this apparently happens because SVG is essentially it's own mini-language (using XML syntax), and it has to parse its body entirely. If there are any other tags that defined an embedded language, they also might do the same thing.

Comment: BTW, `<script>` itself is another tag that causes its contents to be parsed specially -- in this case it *doesn't* look for embedded tags and HTML entities.

Comment: As this post explained, if you add the `<![CDATA[
  …
]]>` in script tag you would be able to parse them like usual: https://jsfiddle.net/sob43r2v/  (possibly related source: https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/docs/QuickStart.html)

Answer (score 0):

An inline SVG in an HTML document is considered as a [*foreign element*](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#foreign-elements) by the parser. Its content is then parsed by the SVG parser, and all the content of this SVGElement is thus parsed as SVG.

SVG has [its own definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/script) of the <script> element, and what you have here is actually an SVGScriptElement, not an HTML one:

```html
<svg>
  <script>
    const thisScript = document.currentScript;
    console.log('HTMLScriptElement?', thisScript instanceof HTMLScriptElement); // false
    console.log('SVGScriptElement?', thisScript instanceof SVGScriptElement); // true
  </script>
</svg>
```

Now as to why the content of an `<svg:script>` element gets parsed as if it were XML before it gets executed, we need to go back a little in time.

[SVG1.1 did define](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/script.html#ScriptElement) its <script> element as

> Categories:
>         None
>   Content model:
>         Any elements or character data.
>   Attributes: ...

This means that SVG1.1, unlike HTML, allows its <script> element to have other content than *character data*. (HTML4 did define script content model as [*Script Data*](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-script), which ultimately mapped to *CDATA*).

SVG tiny 1.2 has since then followed on HTML and does treat <script> content as Character Data, but unfortunately browsers only did implement *vector-effects* from this poor tiny1.2 version, so parsing a script tag is still made following 1.1 rules.

[But incoming SVG2](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/interact.html#ScriptElement should follow here, while it's still being in discussion, meaning that in a near future, we should not need to wrap our code in `//<![CDATA[` blocks anymore, even though it would be a solution for your case:

```html
<svg>
  <script>
    console.log("out", "&gt;"); // >
  //<![CDATA[ 
    // ^- this forces the SVG parser to treat the content as Character Data
    console.log("in", "&gt;"); // &gt;
  //]]>
  </script>
</svg>
```

However beware `<![CDATA[` blocks are not allowed in HTML (hence the `//` js comments) except in *foreign elements*, such as SVG and, MathML, so instead, you may also just want to move your script out of your <svg> element, so that it's part of your HTML document directly.